# MacOS Mojave Desktop Grid spacing

Tags: macos, finder, grid

I was playing around with my Mac settings, and came across View settings for my desktop, thinking whatever I'll do, there will be a defaults button, but I was I wrong.

I edited the desktop's view settings, specifically the grid spacing, and for the life of me, cannot get it back to the default original setting. It just seems off. I've also read the default value is 54, but there are no numbers on the slider, just a visual representation.

I've also read here that using Xcode you can edit it to the default 54, but Xcode is 6GB (too large of a file for my current internet connection in my dormitory), and I cannot even find the `com.apple.finder.plist` file.

In addition, in terminal, It says permission denied when trying to access the .plist file.

How can I change the grid spacing back to normal?

Comment: One thing you might find is that whatever you set for spacing, icons won't move if the text or icon is too big. Grab a bunch of icons, move them all, then see what pattern they form, resize your spacing, try again. Also toggling sort by None, then Snap to Grid can make it re-think. If you sort by any other criterion, that will set the spacing, though it may leave gaps if the names are too long, as above.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am asking for grid spacing for the desktop in MacOS mojave. I tried doing what you told me to, but to no avail. It just isn't the same. I'm wondering if you can help me by taking a screenshot of the slider itself on your Mac, so I can set it to almost the same level on my end and see if that solves the problem, without having to go into the technical stuff. Thank you :)

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what the default is - my current Mac is a direct set of migrations from every Mac I've owned since 2001. It probably also makes a difference whether you have a retina screen or not & what your perception of 'normal' is. I have 2x27" non-retina 1440p screens & I don't like icons like dinner plates, so my settings are probably nowhere near what your perceived defaults would be if you're on a laptop with a retina. The prefs file is in ~/Library/Preferences. My defaults are spacing 37, icon size 28, text size 11 - but I doubt they are the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the desktop/hold control key when you click, and select show view options. The scale for adjusting the grid spacing will be in the box.